# How would I be able to get price of Amazon Product in php?

Tags: php

I've looked all over Google, trying to find out how I could find the price of a product using PHP.

**I'm looking to get the price from the product URL**

I don't want to use the Amazon Web Services as my account was banned and I'm looking for a more simple way of doing it.

I'm not that good with PHP and I've come from Python, I was thinking that you could maybe use something like Regex or match (If those exist in PHP).

Comment: Are you looking to just get the price or anything else?

Comment: I am just loojing to be able to get the price from a url.

Comment: use http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ to parse dom elements

Comment: That looks a little confussing to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some PHP code that will fetch the price, although, if the price is on offer, it will not grab that price, it'll just get the total price of the Amazon Product.

```
//Grab the contents of the Product page from Amazon
$source = file_get_contents("https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01DFKC2SO");

//Find the Price (Searches using Regex)
preg_match("'<span id=\"priceblock_ourprice\" class=\"a-size-medium a-color-price\">(.*?)</span>'si", $source, $match);

//Check if it was actually found.
if($match){
  //Echo Price if it was indeed found.
  echo $match[1]; 
}
```

I'm also unsure if it's possible to do this with both .com and the other versions of Amazon, you'll have to do some searching for the correct tags, classes and/or ids.

**Edit**
As asked for in the comments of this answer, to get the title add this code:

```
//Find the Title (Searches using Regex)
preg_match("'<span id=\"productTitle\" class=\"a-size-large\">(.*?)</span>'si", $source, $match);
if($match){
  echo $match[1];
}
```

Comment: This works, I know that I said that I would only want to be able to get the price, can you give me some code that would get the name of the product too?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [PHPHtmlParser](https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser) package.

> PHPHtmlParser is a simple, flexible, html parser which allows you to
>   select tags using any css selector, like jQuery. The goal is to
>   assiste in the development of tools which require a quick, easy way to
>   scrap html, whether it's valid or not! This project was original
>   supported by sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser but the support seems to
>   have stopped so this project is my adaptation of his previous work.

Then you could use it to extract the price doing something like this:

```
// of course you need to install the package, best done using composer
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PHPHtmlParser\Dom;

$dom = new Dom;
// create a Dom object from the desired url
$dom->loadFromUrl("https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01LOP8EZC/ref=s9_top_hd_bw_b710gst_g63_i1?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-1&pf_rd_r=BP4XPK3DA9H3QTJBWM20&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=2530894322&pf_rd_i=6427871011");
// extract the price from the Dom
$price = $dom->find('#priceblock_ourprice');
print $price->text();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have access to amazon product api, and want to fetch price in bulk, your best bet is to use some other free/paid third-party public API. In our startup we use [amazon-price](https://rapidapi.com/ebappa1971/api/amazon-price) from RapidAPI, it supports up to 1000 products in a single request. We've tried other options but most of them don't support bulk price and/or are more expensive possibly due to the fact that they also provide other data apart from just price.